# VB Syntax: return type of a function, returning a dynamic array of generic lists

Tags: vb.net, function, syntax, return-type

I would like to convert a few lines of VB code into a function call for the sake of compactness and clarity. Currently the code populates a dynamic array of generic lists:

```
Dim itemCount as Integer = 5
Dim myarr(itemCount - 1) As List(Of DataRow)
' some code that populates myarr
```

What would be the syntax of *return type* for a function that would return `myarr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code. The type is `List(Of DataRow)()`, this can also be verified via `TypeName`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim m() As List(Of DataRow)
    m = getTest()
End Sub

Private Function getTest() As List(Of DataRow)()
    Dim m(10) As List(Of DataRow)
    MessageBox.Show(TypeName(m))
    For i = 0 To 10
        m(i) = New List(Of DataRow)
    Next
    Return m
End Function
```

Comment: I cannot at this moment find a definitive reference, but I am sure that it is recommended to declare and assign in one line, so `Dim m() As List(Of DataRow) = getTest()`.

Comment: Declarations at the top is an older standard - since then many have asked: what possible purpose is there to having all variable declarations at the top? If you can think of one, let us know.  Most have found that it's more appropriate closer to the variables usage.

Comment: Either is fine, but from optimization standpoint, it is better to leave it to the compiler instead of having extra variables. From code readability and debug-ability standpoint it is sometimes more convenient to have the local variables on hand.